IRA Hardship Withdrawal - Insurance Premiums
My spouse has been unemployed for more than 12 weeks. She is enrolled in my employer insurance plan, and pays me the difference in premium (Individual vs. Individual + Spouse) every other week. Can she withdraw this amounts from her IRA account and compensate herself?

Insurance premiums are not an unexpected and devastating expense. It's a routine bill.
The definition of "hardship" requires an "immediate and heavy financial need". Routine bills don't really fall into that category. I'm also a bit surprised that she can pay the difference in premium herself, when she's not the one covered by the plan (you are). I suspect that's not exactly what is happening.
That said, for health insurance premiums she pays (where she's the one who's the primary insured and named on the bill, not reimbursing you for your paycheck contributions), IRA withdrawals are allowed without 10% penalty (not under hardship rules, see here). They're still taxable.

The source of this answer is IRS Pub 590-b

Medical insurance.
Even if you are under age 59½, you may not have to pay the 10%
additional tax on distributions during the year that aren't more than
the amount you paid during the year for medical insurance for
yourself, your spouse, and your dependents. You won't have to pay the
tax on these amounts if all of the following conditions apply.

You lost your job.
You received unemployment compensation paid under any federal or state law for 12 consecutive weeks because you lost your job.
You receive the distributions during either the year you received the unemployment compensation or the following year.
You receive the distributions no later than 60 days after you have been reemployed.


You might have to wait a few weeks, because I believe that you don't get unemployment compensation until a week has passed.
The tricky part is this:

That aren't more than
the amount you paid during the year for medical insurance for
yourself, your spouse, and your dependents.

You spouse is reimbursing you for the insurance, they aren't paying the employer or the insurance company.
Also the money withdrawn from the IRA would still be taxed as income, it would only avoid the 10% penalty.

If spouse is reimbursing me for the insurance and not paying the employer or insurance company, which of the bullet points above is violated? If none of those is violated wouldn't she qualify for a IRA withdrawal without the 10 percent penalty?
